# Integrating a ruby program w/ GUI in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

This is somewhat hard for me to explain properly, sorry in advance if the question is unclear! I am fairly new to both Ruby and the Rails framework but I'm working on a Rails application in which I want to be able to run a self-made program with GUI.

The question is whether or not it is possible to just "have" the program running like it otherwise would in a page in the Rails application, and if so, how?

Comment: Use http://shoesrb.com/

Comment: You need to bear in mind that your ruby/rails app runs on a server somewhere and the user interaction happens in a browser on a user's computer.  You can't have a ruby app running in a browser like a flash app.  So, in order for these two different things (server and client) to seem like they are part of the same application there needs to be communication back and forth between them.  This is what rails does, using the "stateless" paradigm which basically means it starts from scratch with every request, although cookies can help maintain the illusion of it having a state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually you can (if the app can be run in multiple instances). But whatever GUI stuff it does on the server won't be of much use to your webclients, it'll just needlessly strain your resources a little bit (or a lot--depending to what graphical operations it does). For web apps, you're better off using non-gui programs or better yet, libraries that you can use from inside ruby without needing to spawn separate processes.

Launching an app incurs a little bit of overhead, which however multiplies by the number of web clients you have.